# Printing strings and integers from a text file (C++)

Tags: c++, string, file, text, integer

I have to read from a text file that contains strings and integers and write a program that finds the oldest person and displays their name.
This is what is on my text file

```
Jefferson 17
Bill 24
Mary 19
Jack 22
Matthew 19
Claudia 23
Judy 18
```

I am having trouble printing the name of the oldest person once I find what the oldest age is. Can anyone walk me through it?

Comment: What code do you have?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Still now what you did yourself? 

Moderator need attention this type of questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store them into a `vector<pair<string, int>>` to associate names with their ages together. Once you find where the oldest age is, you find its name.

If you store them in two separate `vector`s, make sure you keep tracking of them synchronously.

---

**Updated:** For your code (as you commented below), you should change

```
for(int i=1; i<=7;++i) 
{ 
    if(age[i]>max) 
        max=age[i]; 
    name[i]=max; 
    ...
}
```

to

```
string name_oldest;             // to store the oldest name
for(int i=1; i<=7;++i) 
{ 
    if(age[i]>max) 
    {
        max=age[i]; 
        name_oldest = name[i];  // update here
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is what I have so far

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 ifstream f;
 f.open("data.txt");
 string name[7];
 int age[7], max=0;

 for(int i=1; i<=7;++i)
 {
  if(age[i]>max)
  max=age[i];
  name[i]=max;
  cout<<name[i]<<endl;
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

Comment: @user3326689 You can share your code to let us better know what errors caused.

Comment: I changed my code to that but nothing is printing

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 ifstream f;
 f.open("data.txt");
 string name[7];
 int age[7], max=0;

 for(int i=1; i<=7;++i)
 {
  if(age[i]>max) 
  {
   max=age[i]; 
   name[i]=max;
   cout<<name[i];
  }
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

Comment: @user3326689 And don't forget to read data from the file first.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a school assignment, where you have to implement the algorithms yourself, it's actually very easy to solve everything using the [standard C++ library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp):

First you read each line using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instance.

With this string and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) you can then parse out the different fields using the normal input operator `>>`.

You can store the data in a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), with the age as the key and the name as the data. As `std::map` is sorted on key, the last entry in the map is the "oldest" person.

If there can be multiple persons with the same age, then you need to use [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) instead, and be ready to print multiple persons with the same age.